# Is there any information about John Cena's name being in the Episode 4 credits?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

At the end of Minecraft Story Mode Episode 4, in the **Thanks to...** section I saw a familiar name:

[image: JOHNCENA!]

In capitals in the image, it says [John Cena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Cena). We all know that John Cena is a wrestler, right guys? Yes, he's in the credits. We don't know why his name is in the credits as the Wiki doesn't mention. It could be another John Cena, but the best known one is the wrestler. Is there any story of why John Cena's name is in the credits? Did he really get involved in Minecraft Story Mode? Or is it just an Easter Egg?

**EDIT:** I noticed there was also Randy Savage too.

Comment: It's just the "Thanks to" section, his name being there doesn't mean anything. Someone could've had fun watching his fights while coding.

Comment: Heck, Jeff Sinclair is on the list. If it refers to [Jeffrey Sinclair](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Sinclair), then all he could have done was provide inspiration or entertainment to the developers.

Comment: I would say it is just a joke. His name is even exclaimed and with capital letters, so I suppose they do mean the wrestler. There are many cases in which the developers just make fun in the special thanks to. They could've also gotten inspiration from him perhaps